# Storing x-y time series data of experiments in a database

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb

I have a large amount of x & y float data of different laboratory tests, which I want to store in a MariaDB/MySQL database. The data for each test is stored in simple space-delimited  csv-files. I tried to create the database with python, but I have encountered a conceptual problem:

I was thinking that for each test I could store e.g. a TestID and then two float arrays which store the x and y values respectively. However, apparently storing float arrays does not work in MariaDB and up to now I have only found the option to dump the data to JSON or chunks of JSON parts due to the size of the constructed string.

Is there no better way to store experimental time-series data in such a database? I found some similar questions on here, but they never really talked about the part of storing the actual measurements.

Comment: You probably want two tables, linked by a foreign key.  One table for your tests, one for your test data.  I would strongly discourage trying to put all your test data into one string.

Comment: I currently have one table for test metadata and one linked table for the actual results, but this still leaves me with the problem that the results have many x and y values and I don't know how to store them.

Comment: Store the x and y values in a table, with a foreign key?

Comment: I feel dumb, since I'm clearly not grasping something that appears to be easy. Do you have a simple example?

Comment: `CREATE TABLE result_data (id int unsigned not null primary key auto_increment, x float not null, y float not null, result_id int unsigned not null)`, presuming `result_id` is some foreign key to some other (shorter) table.

Comment: not clear what your source date looks like do you have 1 row per test with many x,y pairs? NB sql does not do arrays it does tables and JSON.

Comment: Thanks for the example. I guess my mind was still interpreting each line of the table as a separate result and I somehow wanted to store all x and y stuff in a array on a single result row. Thanks again!

Comment: You could do that, but a) you may end up with storage problems and b) it makes it really hard to search or compare data.  One row per data point will leverage the power of a relational database